# Mac OS X Boot Camp stealing 1GB of RAM from Windows Vista

Tags: macos, windows-vista, boot-camp

I am running Boot Camp 2.2 (just updated the software and restarted) on my Mac Mini, which has 2GB of RAM in it. When I launch Windows Vista, my available RAM is only 1GB (it lists 1.00GB in Computer -> Properties, and only 876MB of TOTAL Physical Memory in Performance under Task Manager). I'm curious as to why this happens...is this a bug or does Boot Camp need that much RAM to launch Windows? Also I would assume that what Windows thinks it has is all it will use...so the performance would downgrade.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your chipset driver (and perhaps other ones) beyond what the Boot Camp software includes. Use [SlimDrivers](http://www.slimdrivers.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No, Vista should recognize your 2GB. If it doesn't is a firmware and/or motherboard driver issue. Most likely the former.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably down to the on-board graphics, the mini uses shared memory for it's graphics, and that memory is reserved by Vista.